# Entity Framework Open DataReader with IQueryable .Include(IQueryable, String)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**EDIT: The original write-up assumed the error was in a particular place, but it does not appear to be. I would appreciate any advice on how to track down where the data reader is getting opened--some way to trace it through EF would be ideal, as I haven't found any way to do that effectively.**

I've run into an issue with Entity Framework giving me open data reader errors, and I'm not sure why.

### Background

I've implemented a generic base repository class for the middle tier of my app. The older version used a generic "FindAll()" method that returned a base class, and we then relied on lazy loading to populate relations in the business logic. Since this doesn't perform as well as eager loading, we added a bunch of "FindByEager" methods which accessed the DbSet directly and used `.Include(t => t.propertyName)` to eager load properties which would be needed later.

### Problem

Inspired by [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) (see under the heading "Create a Generic Repository"), as part of a larger refactor, I'm trying to implement a more generic "FindAll" method that can dynamically add include methods using [DbExtensions.Include(IQueryable, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696450(v=vs.103).aspx). The resulting code in my base repository looks like this:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> FindAll(string includeProperties = "")
    {
        var query = NcContext.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

        foreach (var property in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(property);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

However, Entity Framework just isn't liking this. As I try to iterate over the included-properties string and `.Include` each property, EF wants to treat this as an operation on an open DataReader (the old error of "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first" which appears whenever we try to execute the resulting query).

### Why I think this is the issue

- I've tried following through stack traces and modifying some other methods to make sure every connection I've previously used is getting executed with `.ToList()`. I cannot see anywhere else there could be a data reader left open.
- I'm stepping through this method in the debugger. After passing the `var query = ...` line, I can successfully enumerate the query and get the results. As soon as I've stepped past one of the `.Include()`s (i.e. passed through the foreach loop) if I try to enumerate the query I will hit the issue.

I'd be interested in understanding why this is happening (haven't found much luck looking for documentation on this) and how to fix it. It also breaks my understanding of how Entity works, since shouldn't it be delaying execution of the built query until actual evaluation time?

### Possible solutions I haven't yet tried:

- Passing expressions instead of strings & using the other [`DbExtensions.Include<T, TProperty> (IQueryable<T>, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) overload. Whether this is the solution or not, I'd like to understand why Entity is producing this behavior.
- Pulling the DbSet into memory with `.ToList()`. I am trying to allow at least a little reusability for consuming classes to fine-tune the queries they're running, so I want to return a `Queryable`, and forcing execution of the query then reconverting to Queryable doesn't seem very efficient.

Regardless of whether these will fix it (will update if they do), I'd be interested in knowing what I was doing wrong here and why it works this way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I use the same approach without any error. Look for error somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei -- I've edited the question to make it clearer why I think this is the location of the issue.

Comment: Write some code using a new instance of your context and see the result. `var db = new MyContext; var q = db.Set<Something>().AsQueryable(); q = q.Include("P1"); q = q.Include("P2"); var result = q.ToList();`

Comment: @RezaAghaei you are correct; writing a little test harness to create a new DbContext and that works fine. There must be a previous leak then--would you have any suggestions for how to go about finding it?

Comment: It completely depends on implementation. Unfortunately I have no idea about the reason of the problem.